# How to transform custom XML to Ruby ActiveResource XML format

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT, please help.
We have an XML which we want to convert it into Ruby ActiveResource format XML. Please help me with the XSLT code. Thank you.

**XML INPUT**

```
<PARM>
<PC>0</PC>
<PMT NM="THEME" DN="THEME" IR="0" T="0">
    <PV V="fast" L="" H="" C="4"/>
</PMT>
<PMT NM="INGREDIENTS" DN="INGREDIENTS" IR="0" T="0">
    <PV V="chicken" L="" H="" C="5"/>
    <PV V="tomato" L="" H="" C="12"/>
</PMT>
</PARM>
```

**REQUIRED XML OUTPUT**

```
<facet-groups type="array">
 <facet-group>
  <name>THEME</name>
  <facets type="array">
    <facet>
      <name>fast</name>
      <count>4</count>
    </facet>
  </facets>
 </facet-group>
 <facet-group>
  <name>INGREDIENTS</name>
  <facets type="array">
    <facet>
      <name>chicken</name>
      <count>5</count>
    </facet>
    <facet>
      <name>tomato</name>
      <count>12</count>
    </facet>
  </facets>
 </facet-group>
</facet-groups>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: On which basis you define `PMT` an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the @LarsH in other words:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="PARM">
        <facet-groups type="array">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PMT"/>
        </facet-groups>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PMT">
        <facet-group>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="@NM"/></name>
            <facets type="array">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PV"/>
            </facets>
        </facet-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PV">
        <facet>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="@V"/></name>
            <count><xsl:value-of select="@C"/></count>
        </facet>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the code, it saved me. Yes, next time I will make sure to put some code written by me. Thank you.

Comment: I've changed the title  (as sometime do for accepted answers) to match the question. Be free to revert to the original if you care about it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Keoki said, you should show more of what you've done, before it would be appropriate to give you a whole solution. But to get started, you would create

- a template matching "PARM", that outputs a `facet-groups` element and within that, applies templates to children
- a template matching "PMT", that outputs a `facet-group` element, with children `<name>` and `<facets>`, and within the latter, applies templates to children
- a template matching "PV", that outputs a `facet` element, with children `<name>` and `<count>`

Hopefully that will give you a good start.